# Php value change in database when time period is met

Tags: php, sql

Hello currently working on my management system.
So my problem is my student has a field of status. and has 2 values Enrolled and Not enrolled.
Currently my enroll is working. My idea is once the system date would be April the students status would change from enroll to Not Enrolled , and when the students enrolled the status would change to enrolled no problem with the enroll part just the not enrolled part.

Would appreciate any ideas on how to perform this. Currently i am imagining an If else on my enroll page.

Comment: u can add one small function at the beginning / top of ur codes that will check the date.
when the date matched, the code will run MySQL command to update related student's status.
that is the simplest way i can think of

Comment: @s3polz thank you  . . i think will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a new `DATE` column to the table and save only enrolled students information:

```
TABLE NAME: AAE_ENROLLED //(AAE stands for your initials ;) )
COLUMN 1: STUDENT_ID TYPE VARCHAR(50)
COLUMN 2: ENROLLMENT_DATE TYPE DATE
```

Say that you want all the students that enrolled after the beginning of April, all you have to do is:

```
select * from AAE_ENROLLED 
where ENROLLMENT_DATE > STR_TO_DATE('2012-04-01','%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you want to find students which where NOT enrolled you can use `NOT EXIST`

Comment: This is helpful to my enroll side. But my main problem is once the system date is april all will enrolled statuses would be changed to not enrolled.

Comment: You don't need to un-enroll them, that's why the query selects students that enrolled AFTER april start ;)

Comment: Hmmm interesting i will look into this method. Thank you. But i don't still fully understand it. No matter i will try.